# Selenium grid and azure

Tags: java, azure, webdriver, cloud, selenium-grid

we use VSTS to build apps but this all is not on remote machine but in cloud. I need to run selenium grid on this cloud to run my tests on nodes, how can i do it?If it was a remote machine that's ok login remotly and run grid hub from cmd but it's a cloud so is it possible to run grid hub?

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding, it seems that you want to run selenium grid on Azure to run your test. If you are using Azure Web App, you can install Selenium Grid Hub as site extension on Azure via Kudu tool, please see below.

1. Access the Kudu tool of your Azure WebApp and move to the tab `Site extensions` via the url `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/?#gallery`, as follow the steps of the figure below.

[image]

2. View the `README.md` of [selenium grid hub site extension on GitHub](https://github.com/gregjhogan/selenium-grid-hub-site-extension) to know how to use it and do your test.

> **Selenium-Grid Hub site extension for Azure**
>
> Once installed, navigate to http://.azurewebsites.net/grid/console to see the grid console
>
> (you may need to stop and start the web app to get it to pick up the applicaitonhost.config changes)
>
> limitations
>
> - if you enable HTTPS the hub runs but I cannot get nodes to join over HTTPS :(
> - authentication seems important when running a hub in the cloud, but I don't know how to add support for this

Hope it helps.